# PHP call_user_func vs función variable

Tags: php, funciones, clase, rendimiento

Estoy llamando un método dentro de una clase de manera dinámica y ahora me ha surgido una duda. Sobre cual de los 2 métodos es mas rápido, consume menos recursos, es más eficiente.

Por ejemplo:

```
class example {
    function x ($params) {}
    function y ($params) {}
    function z ($params) {}
    function ejecutar1 ($method, $params){
      // Method 1
      if (method_exists($this, $method) && is_callable($this, $method))
          call_user_func_array (array($this, $method), array($params));
    }
    function ejecutar2 ($method, $params){
      // Method 2
      if (method_exists($this, $method) && is_callable($this, $method))
          $this->$method($params);
    }
}
```

No me interesa la evaluación sobre si la el método existe, o la clase existe. **Solo necesito saber cual es la manera más eficiente de llamar a un método dentro de una clase, cuando el nombre del método lo tengo en un STRING**. Tanto para la versión 5.6 como las versiones mas recientes de PHP (ya que debería variar dependiendo de la versión)

> Para el ejemplo solo seria llamar a una de las funciones de la clase. Quiero saber cual método es mas eficiente y el porqué.

```
$clase = new example();
$Metodos = array ('x', 'y', 'z');
foreach ($Metodos as $method) {
   $clase->ejecutar1($method, 'PARAMETROS');
   $clase->ejecutar2($method, 'PARAMETROS');
}
```

Comment: Tratando de entender para qué sirve tu `clase`, parecería como si se alejase de la POO. ¿Para qué serviría precisamente esa clase? ¿Cómo sería su uso?

Comment: @A.Cedano He actualizado mi pregunta. Principalmente lo que hace la clase es indiferente, la pregunta es cual sería mas eficiente. O qué otra forma seria mas eficiente que las anteriores, seria también interesante. Los parámetros son enviados a un webservice, el método viene en el encabezado, codificado por ello es indiferente el uso.

Comment: tendrías que hacer tests de rendimiento, `call_user_func_array` por lo general yo lo uso para inyectar mas parámetros, ó si el nombre del método está contenido en un array u otra estructura por ejemplo `$model_extra_call_result = call_user_func_array( array( $this->$sujeto, $extra_action_data['call_function']),$extra_action_data['call_default_params']);` es diferente a `$result = $this->$sujeto->delete_registro($reg_id);`

Comment: hay una discusión interesante en este hilo : https://stackoverflow.com/q/18526060/1423096

Comment: @aloMalbarez podrías expandir tu comentario en una respuesta?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te contaba en los comentarios la mejor manera de saber es correr tests de rendimiento, si sabes de antemano la estructura de llamada la mas eficiente pareciera ser la llamada directa `$this->$method($params);` en el caso de mi ejemplo tengo una clase (controlador) que instancia otras clases (modelos) las cuales son extend de una clase base, con lo cual hay metodos que ya sé que existen (de la clase base), y otros metodos/funciones que se exponen como "llamables" con sus "parametros defaults" entre otras cosas.

En el ejemplo dado `$this->$sujeto->$accion($params);` es legible y directo pues ya se que `$sujeto` es un modelo y `$accion` es un metodo base y por ende ya tengo/conozco el formato y cantidad de los `$params`, en partes no tan dinámicas llamo al metodo base por su nombre por ejemplo `$result = $this->$sujeto->delete_registro($reg_id);` .

En otros casos (funciones/metodos extra que son específicos del modelo) tengo un array (previamente generado y filtrado por rol del usuario actual) que por un lado arma el menú de opciones para la vista (nombre corto para url, nombre largo para mostrar en menu) y por otro lado se encarga de mantener la info para llamar a la función extra con sus parámetros correctos (nombre del método/funcion dentro del modelo, parametros esperados, parámetros opcionales, etc...) . Esto se traduce en:

```
// so we have user extra actions, get um
$allowed_extra_actions =
    $this->current_user_allowed_extra_actions[$sujeto];
if (isset($allowed_extra_actions[$item])) :
    // the extra action is allowed, get real name and current params
    $extra_action_data = $allowed_extra_actions[$item];
    // play it safe check if action exists
    if (method_exists(
        $this->$sujeto, $extra_action_data['call_function']
    )
    ) :
        $model_extra_call_result =
            call_user_func_array(
                array(
                    $this->$sujeto,
                    $extra_action_data['call_function']
                ),
                $extra_action_data['call_default_params']
            );
    endif;
endif;
```

este último bloque de código también podría ser escrito como :

```
$model_extra_action = $extra_action_data['call_function'];
$model_extra_params = $extra_action_data['call_default_params'];
$model_extra_call_result = $this->$sujeto->$model_extra_action(...$model_extra_params);
```

con la "contra" de que el `(...$params)` sólo es compatible con php 5.6+ (y no se puede llamar metodos estaticos antes de php 7), la diferencia de rendimiento suele ser bastante mejor usando el `(...$params)` pero naturalmente se pierde compatibilidad.

En resumen si no necesitas `call_user_func_array` para alguna acrobacia, usar el `$this->$method($params);` ó en caso de que acepte varios parámetros y la compatibilidad es php 5.6+ `$this->$method(...$params);` es lo mas aconsejable debido al rendimiento.

Answer (score 0):

Podríamos decir que **ninguno de los dos**, porque existe un método para verificar, desde fuera de la clase, si un determinado método existe en ella o no, se trata de **[`method_exists`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.method-exists.php)**.

Veamos tu clase, *liberada*  de algo para lo cual ella no debería existir:

```
class example {
    function x ($params) {}
    function y ($params) {}
    function z ($params) {}
}
```

Ahora probemos desde fuera de ella:

```
$clase = new example();
$Metodos = array ('x', 'y', 'z', 'esteNo');

foreach ($Metodos as $method) {
    echo method_exists($clase,$method) ? "El método $method SÍ Existe".PHP_EOL : "El método $method NO existe".PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Salida:**

```
El método x SÍ Existe
El método y SÍ Existe
El método z SÍ Existe
El método esteNo NO existe
```

Comment: He actualizado la función. El problema no es verificar si el método existe o no. Mi pregunta es simplemente cual de los 2 métodos que expongo es mas eficiente para llamar a un método dentro de una clase.

Comment: @DMAVE en tu pregunta dice esto: ***Eventualmente se tiene que validar que la funcion exista y no tenga problemas en ejecutar la función.*** ¿No es eso lo que hace el código de mi respuesta? y además donde tiene que hacerlo, ya que las `clases` no son para validar dentro de ellas mismas si sus métodos existen... no le veo ningún sentido a eso, ese no es el propósito de las `clases`. Y encima ahora trasladaste el método de mi respuesta dentro de la clase. Es que no, estás ejecutando un pésimo diseño haciendo eso, una `clase` es otra cosa.

Comment: Disculpa si me mal interpretaste... Pero lo primero que escribí en mi pregunta es "Estoy utilizando clases dinámicas y **ahora me ha surgido una duda. Sobre cual de los 2 métodos es mas rápido, consume menos recursos, es más eficiente**." El título de la pregunta es "**PHP call_user_func vs función variable**" en tu respuesta solo validas y evaluas el método que se envía. Como te dije anteriormente "lo que hace la clase en sí es indiferente" es solo una referencia.

Comment: @DMAVE si son *clases dinámicas*  entonces lo que deberías evaluar es si la clase existe, no si el método existe. En cualquier caso, insisto en que la `clase` no debería tener dentro de ella ninguna función para validar si una función dada existe en ella. ¿Tú para qué crees que existe `method_exists` entonces? Si tú metes toda esa comprobación dentro de la clase ocurren dos cosas: 1. que estarás casi sin duda violando los principios de la POO; 2. estás optando por un método de pésimo rendimiento comparado con una evaluación externa, pues por cada método que quieras verificar tendrás...

Comment: ... que hacer una llamada al método de la clase que debe evaluar si ella tiene ese método. Si en el momento que creas la instancia de la clase dispones del array de métodos que se deben evaluar (como has mostrado en la pregunta) lo más eficaz es evaluar ahí si los métodos existen o no. Fíjate que haciéndolo así, no tocas la clase para nada. Es evidente que es mucho más eficaz así y tu clase queda libre de un método para controlarse a sí misma... aunque en realidad, tampoco deberían existir llamadas *locas*  a métodos de clases que no existan, pero eso sería ya otra historia.

Comment: Joder el problema no es saber si existe el método, jajajaja. Solo quiero saber que forma es mas eficiente para **llamar** a un método dentro de una clase. Relee la pregunta

Comment: @DMAVE un benchmark simple aplicando mi respuesta da un resultado de `0.0068018436431885` sobre `100,000` verificaciones de si los métodos existen en la clase. En cuanto a trasladar los métodos dentro de la clase misma, el resultado es: `0.12350487709045` para `ejecutar1` y de `0.11344718933105` para `ejecutar2`
. A menor valor, más rendimiento. Si probamos con 1 millón de iteracciones, tenemos para cada caso: `0.0059700012207031` / `1.0517058372498` / `0.11114311218262`  y si probamos con 5 millones de iteracciones: `0.0077390670776367`/ `3.3189108371735` / `0.10542416572571`